# Auto Increment index using findAndModify with Li3 throwing error

Tags: lithium

I'm following [this post](http://shiflett.org/blog/2010/jul/auto-increment-with-mongodb) to get an auto increment id instead of using the mongoid but getting error

```
    Method `_connection` not defined or handled in class.
```

It makes sense because I can't find a function called _connection anywhere. Is it due to an outdated version of Lithium? Am I missing something or how can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method is public as of 1.0: http://li3.me/docs/api/lithium/1.0.x/lithium/data/Model::connection()